# react-native-torch report "Cannot read property 'switchState' of null" error

Tags: react-native

I try to run the demo code of [react-native-torch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-torch/v/1.2.0), but it cause error:

```
Cannot read property 'switchState' of null
```

My codes is below:

```
import React from 'react'; import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'; import Torch from 'react-native-torch';

export default class App extends React.Component {   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isTorchOn: false,
    };   }

  _handlePress() {
    const { isTorchOn } = this.state;
    Torch.switchState(!isTorchOn);
    this.setState({ isTorchOn: !isTorchOn });   }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          RCTTorch Demo
        </Text>
        <Button
          onPress={this._handlePress.bind(this)}
          title="Toggle Torch"
        />
      </View>
    );   
  } 
}
```

So how is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the app.

Delete the app from your device and then run:

1. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ../`
2. `yarn start --reset-cache`
3. `yarn android`

I am not sure if you have to do steps 1 and 2 but i did them and it worked for me.